# How are the controller and model linked in ProjectPier

Tags: projectpier

I am currently working on extending ProjectPier. I am having trouble deciphering how the controller is linked to the model, and how the model is linked with the database (naming convention, direct declaration, etc...) Apparently Project Pier was developed with an obscure framework called Angie, which has no documentation whatsoever. Any experts on this? Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should try posting on the forum, or emailing the maintainers for hints. http://www.projectpier.org/forums/development/general-development-forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out myself after some tinkering. There is no 'automagic' between the controller and model in ProjectPier. Models are simply referenced by their class name.

There is also no naming convention inside the model. Each table is associated with 4 model files however. Application_log.class.php and Application_logs.class.php are the functional files. Each of these have an associated base class from which they inherit: Base_Application_log.class.php, and Base_Application_logs.class.php. Inside the Base_Application_logs.class.php there is a line in the __construction function which links with the specific database table:  `parent::__construct('Application_log', 'table_name', true);`

That's it! The rest is pretty straight forward. Hope this can be of some help for someone in the future!

Comment: Any help with this....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32175026/projectpier-custom-feature-module-estimation???